# Last Function in Query

Tags: ms-access-2010

So I currently have a database that keeps tracks of projects, project updates, and the update dates. I have a form that with a subform that displays the project name and the most recent update made to said project.  It was brought to my attention however, that the most recent update to a project does not display correctly. Ex: shows the update date of 4/6/2017 but the actual update text is from 3/16/2017.

Doing some spot research, I then learned that Access does not store records in any particular order, and that the Last function does not actually give you the last record.

I am currently scouring google to find a solution but to no avail as of yet and have turned here in hopes of a solution or idea. Thank you for any insight you can provide in advance!

Other details:
tblProjects has fields

- ID
- Owner
- Category_ID
- Project_Name
- Description
- Resolution_Date
- Priority
- Resolution_Category_ID

tblUpdates has these fields:

- ID
- Project_ID
- Update_Date
- Update

Answer (score 0):

there is no built-in Last function that I am aware of in Access or VBA, where exactly are you seeing that used?

if your sub-form is bound directly to tblUpdates, then you ought to be able to just sort the sub-form in descending order based on either ID or Update_date.

if you have query joining the two tables, and are only trying to get a single row returned from tblUpdates, then this would do that, assuming the ID column in tblUpdates is an autonumber. if not, just replace ORDER BY ID with ORDER BY Update_Date Desc

```
SELECT a.*,
   (SELECT TOP 1  Update FROM tblUpdates b WHERE a.ID =  b.PROJECT_ID ORDER BY ID DESC ) AS last_update
FROM tblProjects AS a;
```

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SQL-Aggregate-Functions-a810ee71-c1cd-43d7-9c55-8005f1893be5

Comment: in the design view of the query, when you press the Totals button, it'll be a drop down selection in the group by where you can choose First or Last. I'll try your suggestion and let you know how it goes thanks :D